# Print quality: possible Z wobble

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting, z-axis, artillery-sidewinder-x1

The printer I am using is an Artillery Sidewinder X1. In the photos attached you can see that I am having a lot of inconsistency between layers.
The problem has never gone away and I always thought it was Z wobble but now I'm not so sure it is because we have tightened everything up, making sure everything is stable and tight.
Is this Z wobble or is it something else. Could it be the filament? Does it have anything to do with the slicer settings?

[image: 3Dbenchy]

[image]

Comment: that marks are due heating problem vs quality filament vs speed printing. I had the same few years ago.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track. I will look into those three things and post an answer if I fix it.

Comment: For me this also look like overextrusion and heat- notice the drops in the middle of boardside's lower part. Also, corners (booth, bow) seems emphasized - and if it's not filament (too much + too hot = pressure) then maybe too little jerk?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not Z-wobble, Z-wobble is usually characterized by a repetitive distortion, from the supplied images this repetitive pattern is not observed. A Z-wobble pattern is typically caused by the lead screws, or the Z drive where carriage follows the X/Y motion of the lead screw nut.

A typical image of Z-wobble on a Benchy would look like:

[image]

Your print doesn't look that bad for a low-end 3D printer.